# how to checkbox checked for all in listbox datasource in wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

while selecting all means renaming all the checkbox are checked. my code is below:

```
<ListBox  Name="VillageList">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isCheched}"  Content="{Binding Villages}"  IsChecked="False"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

so all checkbox are inside the listbox.how to checked is enable for all checkbox single selection.

```
public class  villageinformation
{
    public string Villages{get;set;}
    public bool isChecked {get;set;}
}

page.cs{

list<villageinformation> mydataSource=new list<villageinformation>();
myDataSource.Add(new villageinformation(){Village="All",isChecked ="False"});
myDataSource.Add(new villageinformation(){Village="name1",isChecked ="False"});
myDataSource.Add(new villageinformation(){Village="name2",isChecked ="False"});
myDataSource.Add(new villageinformation(){Village="name3",isChecked ="False"});


VillageList.itemSource=myDataSource;
}
```

so while clicking manually  "All" checkbox remaining name1,2,3 are selected how to do this?

Comment: Show the code of ListBox and your DataSource and show how you are databinding.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912623/how-to-get-checked-checkbox-content-in-windows-phone-app/41542387#41542387

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ObservableCollection for your villages list, which is used for the data binding to the ListBox, then you can set all values in the ObservalbeCollection in the codebehind which shoul update the UI (by checking all the Checkboxes)

you can do it something like this

```
foreach(var village in VillagesCollection)
{
  village.isChecked = true;
}
```

If you are not able to understand the above, edit your question with how you are setting up the Village data in the code behind file (means .xaml.cs file)