# How to get checked checkbox content in windows phone app?

Tags: c#, checkbox, windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app .In app,I want to put multiple check box.I able to put multiple check box.But when i checked on check box i want getting its content(check box content).For that i am use checked event and also click event but i cant get result as i want.My xaml code is as below:

```
        <ListBox Name="hobbylist" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,10,10" >

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <CheckBox Name="hobbycheck" Content="{Binding Path=Title}"

                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" ClickMode="Release" 

                Click="CheckBox_Click" ></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

Please help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the `Checkbox` not correctly according to its purpose.

`Checkbox` should represent a state (e.g. yes/no) regarding a subject. Still, you just have to use the `Checked` event when the checkbox gets checked and `Unchecked` otherwise.

So in the `Checked` event, get the content you wish.

**Edit**

You have to maintain this with the MVVM pattern somehow. For that, there are plenty of examples in the internet, I am sure you can handle that.

Instead of having `Click="CheckBox_Click"`, use the `Check` event :

```
private void CheckBox_Checked (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentCheckBoxItem = sender as CheckBox;
    if (currentCheckBoxItem.IsChecked == true)
        {
             //you manipulation here...
        }
}
```

Still. this might just not work, because you haven't provided enough details of your matter.

**Edit 2** A little of MVVM...

First, make a  `Hobby` model class, with a single string property (you might change your mind later to add more properties, Idk) :

```
public class Hobby : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected 
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        } 
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //You can add some multiple properties here (***)

    public Hobby (string hobbyName, bool isSelected)
    {
         Name = hobbyName;
         IsSelected = isSelected;
    }

    //INotifiyPropertyChanged interface member implementation ...
}
```

**(*** )** For example, a short description and then bind it on the View. The major advantage of this MVVM pattern is logic separation, so if something has to change, the separation of each component makes it easier.

Second, create a ViewModel class (you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface) :

```
public class HobbiesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Hobby> _hobbies;

    public ObservableCollection<Hobby> HobbiesCollection
    {
         get 
         {
             return _hobbies;
         }
         set
         {
             _hobbies = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
    }

    //Constructor
    public HobbiesViewModel
    {
        HobbiesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Hobby>();
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged interface member implementation ...
}
```

Third, create an instance of the ViewModel (the ObservableCollection). Use this quick help out : In the `App.xaml.cs`, create a static object and use it through the app as you need it :

```
public partial class App
{

//This already exists in your app's code, but I've written it to
//make an idea where to write the Hobbies object
public static PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }

public static HobbiesViewModel Hobbies;

//Again, the already existing constructor
public App()
{
   ...

   Hobbies = new HobbiesViewModel();
}
```

Now, you almost have it all set; You have the Model, you have the ViewModel, all that's left is to create the connection with the View. This can be easily done through binding. The ViewModel represents the `DataContext` of your control (in your case the `LongListSelector`, so in that View's (Page's) constructor, write the following statement :

```
yourListControlName.DataContext = App.Hobbies;
```

Now the binding is the only thing left. This is done in XAML code. I won't put a whole chunk of XAML code here, cause you know best how your control looks like. Still, judging by the short sample you provided, there a few adjustments only :

The items source of the list XAML control will be bound to the `ObservableCollection` object name of the `ViewModel` representing the control's `DataContext`. A bit fuzzy, huh? To be clearer, in this case, you need to write `ItemsSource="{Binding HobbiesCollection}"`, the `ObservableCollection`. Also, in the template, you should have that `CheckBox` which is bound on your `Model`'s properties :

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> //StackPanel is kinda useless if you have
                                          //only one child control in it. But I wrote
                                          //according to your code.
        <Checkbox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, here things are a bit unclear to me. Why would you use the Checkbox? I've thought of the next possible scenario : You come with some string of your hobbies through deserialization of the Json Data. To add them to the `ViewModel`, you need only :

```
App.Hobbies.HobbiesCollection.Add(new Hobby("firstHobbyFromJson", true));
App.Hobbies.HobbiesCollection.Add(new Hobby("secondHobbyFromJson", true));
```

This would make all hobbies already selected in the `View`. I guess, you would add some other hobbies, the user doesn't have which are not selected and could add them now :

```
App.Hobbies.HobbiesCollection.Add(new Hobby("aNewHobby", false));
App.Hobbies.HobbiesCollection.Add(new Hobby("anotherNewHobby", false));
```

At this point, the user has all its previous hobbies in the list and as well some new hobbies you provided him. After his selection is done, if you need to serialize the Json with only the selected hobbies, you could get like this :

```
var userHobbies = App.Hobbies.HobbiesCollection.Where(h => h.IsSelected);
```

or with a foreach and get only those hobby objects which have the `IsSelected` property as `true`.

Good luck!

Comment: First of all thank you replay.Can you so me code.?I want that checked value because i want to serialized it in json and then send it database.Can you give me some example ?it will be easy to understood me that what i had forgot or what is my mistake.?

Comment: You have to provide some more details of your problem. In essence, what I wanted to outline is that you are using the wrong event. If you want something to happen when ONLY checking the checkbox (not happening at uncheck), use the `Checked` event.

Comment: i have one page in which i display hobby .which is i get by deserialized of my Web Client response .now when user mark check on hobby check box that all the hobby is i want in one particular list or array.then serialized it in json to send update hobby in user profile.

Comment: when you get the list of hobbies after the deserialization, you should build some ViewModels (MVVM) to be shown on the View (the page), the users makes the changes (selects/deselects, etc), then analyze the LongListSelecter's ItemSource to get the changed hobbies and reconstruct the format to send with Json, to update the profile.

Comment: yes sir,I want exactly same as you understood ,but i am new to this technology so i am not aware about mvvm so can you help me? to solve this issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer with MVVM details of the how should be implemented. It couldn't exactly match your case, but at least in a big part, it should, cause, it's about MVVM we're speaking.

Comment: Thnak you so much it help me alot .but one question arise in my mind is that insted of checkbox content if i want to serilized hobby on the basis of selceted hobby id /num ? than how i will do it? and if i want to perform it without mvvm pattern than how it should be done.

Comment: MVVM pattern is not here to help you with serialization/deserialization. The process is as follows : deserialization of hobbies >> MVVM in action (aka Selection/Deselection of Hobbies in a Page) >> after user is done with it, Serialization and sending where you need to update the profile.

Comment: I can't really imagine how you could do this without MVVM... Basically you have a list of dynamic items (don't know how they look or how many they are), so you can't do some static display on the Page with checkboxes or other elements. That's why Binding comes to help you out, and also the MVVM. The purpose of this is creating easy to maintain and reusable code. You could add new properties to the Model but the MVVM example still works, it's just you haven't bound them to the View. That's the purpose of logic separation into layers with clear attributes.

Comment: Also, the last piece of code `var userHobbies = App.Hobbies.HobbiesCollection.Where(h => h.IsSelected);`, creates you a List of all the hobbies (as `Hobby` class type object) that were selected by the user. Then if you need only the name, take the strings, put it in a structure of your convenient, and serialize it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting ,your comment clear my problem in some intact .can i know your email id? I will give you my code as well as my design.and again thanks for helping me .

Comment: If I have more than 100 hobbies than it so uncommon to write every hobbies by manually . i want to bind 40+ hobbies in list box .how can i implement?I need your help to solve my problem .

Comment: Here I don't really understand your situation. Let's say you have 10 available hobbies. From the Json, you come with how many? Let's say if an user has 7 hobbies. But in total there are 10. So the list should have 3 unselected and 7 selected? The hobbies to shown on the list must be added manually, yes... in the ViewModel class you can make a method to be executed in the ViewModel constructor, with adding `Hobby` objects... As many as you need. Plus those from the |Json... I don\t really understant your situation.

Comment: Vasile Marian Fălămaș i ask you for email id because i sent my complete code so that you clearly understood what is the problem.so that you can help me more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Simpler solution.

My Model

You need to use two variables otherwise you may get an 'stackoverflowexception'

```
    public class ModelObj
    {
        public int position { set; get; }
        public bool isChecked
        {
            get { return IsChecked; }
            set { IsChecked = value; }
        }
        public bool IsChecked;
    }
```

Code to be added in xaml:

1. isChecked in xaml sets the ListView Checkbox
2. Mode=TwoWay updates the isChecked boolean value of the model class

   ```
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked , Mode=TwoWay}"  Checked="checkBox_Checked" >
   ```

c# Code that handles the event

```
   private void checkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ModelObj obj in listItem)
        {
            if (obj.isChecked == true)
            {
                int selectedPosition = obj.position;
            }

        }
    }
```