# Windows phone 8.1 listView checkbox position

Tags: xaml, listview, checkbox, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have ListView with an image.[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwiUM.png)

and while displaying checkboxes for selecting these images, these checkboxes are aligned to the top. but i want to align the checkBoxes at the center of the image [To be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBkTg.png)
How do I align checkboxes in listview?

```
<ListView Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding PetrolCompany}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSourse}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow:) Please familiarize yourself with how to ask a good question. You should provide us a code with what you already tried. Good Luck ;)

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: @DawidPi I gave you code but you still have not answered after a year

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912623/how-to-get-checked-checkbox-content-in-windows-phone-app/41542387#41542387

Comment: @CloyMonis just exactly in time! :D thanks...

Comment: @mister_giga...... If you found my solution right then upvote it