# How to perform action when CheckBox list view item is selected?

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, xamarin, xlabs

I have a Xamarin.Forms project where I am using Xlabs to implement checkboxes. I can get them to appear which is great. I want to be able to do this:

```
void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        var selectedStudent = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem as Student;

        // set time of student checkin
    }
```

But with my check boxes. I want to be able to handle checkbox selection as it happens. From what I've seen online I can set a new boolean property of my student object `selected`, but that simply doesn't work with my project. Here is my current approach:

```
    void OnSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox isCheckedOrNot = (CheckBox)sender;
        var name = isCheckedOrNot.DefaultText;

        //not sure what to do here?
        var student = ((CheckBox)sender)...

        // set time of student checkin
    }
```

**EDIT:** checkbox declared as so:

```
<ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.View>
        <controls:CheckBox DefaultText="{Binding complete_name}"  TextColor="Black" CheckedChanged="OnSelection" Checked="{Binding selected}"/>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: but will that allow me to know immediately when I couch the check box that it has been touched? `CheckedItems` seems like something something you do after the fact to do something to all the items you selected

Comment: I wasn't aware of this? I get a build error when trying to use saying there is no property of name `ItemChecked`

Comment: I guess I am not sure how I could implement `ItemChecked` event if I declare the checkbox in xaml?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the x-tags.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912623/how-to-get-checked-checkbox-content-in-windows-phone-app/41542387#41542387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very new to xaml/c# so I apologize for asking this bad question but it is as simple as saying:

```
    void OnSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox isCheckedOrNot = (CheckBox)sender;
        var selectedStudent = isCheckedOrNot.BindingContext as Student;
        ...
    }
```

to get the item that you checked.